# Best plugin for Solr integration for ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, solr

What's the best plugin to integrate Solr with Ruby on Rails?

acts_as_solr is outdated. any other ones ?

Comment: do you mean Solr integration modules for Ruby? Or Rails?

Comment: yes. I'm sorry.  for ruby on rails;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hear many people are using [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/).

Comment: Yes, I think Sunspot should be the best one too.

Comment: +1 from the de-facto maintainer of acts_as_sunspot and an active developer on Sunspot ;)

Comment: +1. there is acts_as_solr_reloaded. but it lacks documentation and has smaller community.

Comment: I have used sunspot on several projects and it exposes all the features I have ever needed and has a *really* nice API.